# How to model hopfield neural network for shortest path - vb?

Tags: vb.net, neural-network

how to use the hopfield neural network for calculating shortest path especially on vb ... given the inputs of Dijkstra and getting finally the path

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.